# Connecting to IMAP via StreamSocket in WinRT / C#

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-8, windows-runtime

Trying to write a simple bit of code to connect to an IMAP server using StreamSocket. It reads the server connect response, but then it won't read anything else.

```
    private async void TCPTest(string hostName, string port)
    {
        status.Text = "start of TCPTest";

        StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
        await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(hostName), port);

        string senddata = "A001 login uuu ppp";

        status.Text += "\n first reading...";
        DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
        reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        await reader.LoadAsync(1024);
        string data = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        status.Text += "\n > read " + data;

        status.Text += "\n writing...";
        writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        writer.WriteString(senddata);
        await writer.StoreAsync();
        status.Text += "\n > wrote " + sendata;

        status.Text += "\n second reading...";
        writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        await reader.LoadAsync(1024);
        string data2 = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        status.Text += "\n >" + data2;

        status.Text += "\n end of TCPTest";
    }
```

This is the output I get.

```
start of TCPTest
first reading...
> read * OK mydomain.com IMAP4rev1 MDaemon 13.0.1 ready
writing...
> wrote A001 login uuu ppp
second reading...
```

The app never gets any further than this. There's no error, it just hangs. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? My code is the same (more or less) as the [StreamSocket example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150599.aspx)

Comment: You need to be sure when you write something that it is done reading.
If not this can hang the socket or looks like there is nothing done. But no errors

Comment: how do I do that? while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0) or something similar?

Comment: forgot to terminate the command. doh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't terminating my command. Adding `Environment.Newline` to the end solved things.

Comment: Can you explain what happened? Did you forgot to add "\r\n" or simply "CRLF" to the end of query?

Comment: I didn't add \r\n to the end of the query, so it was unterminated. I could have fixed it by adding \r\n but I used the `Environment.Newline` property in c# which is the same as adding \r\n. I find the syntax a little easier to read though.

Comment: Fantastic! Had the same issue. This post helped a lot!